# Creating sortable table in Rails application with searching/filtering functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to make a UI table in Rails application. It will contain a search box and sort fields. What would be the best approach for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a table in HTML with Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659585/creating-a-table-in-html-with-ruby)

Answer (score 3):

You can use  http://tablesorter.com/docs/ for sorting

and

http://gregweber.info/projects/uitablefilter for in place searching.

or

you can try meta search gem for background searching

https://github.com/ernie/meta_search